# Getting "403 forbidden" error for ajax call web service in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-services, jquery

i have a web service in a server, and i could connect web service from any browser in remote machine or host machine. But i couldn't access the web service using ajax call in javascript, showing 403 forbidden error. I ran the script from the server itself. Below is the code i used.

$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){

```
        var username = 'vijay';
        var password = 'vijay';
        var domain = '';
        var windowsuser = false;
       // var dataObject = {};
       //  dataObject = {Username:username,Password:password,Domain:domain,WindowsUser:windowsuser};

         $('#login').click(function(){

                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/Y_NAME/REST/session.aspx",
                    data: ({Username:username,Password:password,Domain:domain,WindowsUser:windowsuser}),
                 //   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    timeout: 5000,
                    success: onSuccess
                });      

            });               


         $("#resultLog").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, exception) {
          $("#resultLog").html("Error Calling: " + settings.url + "<br />HTTP Code: " + request.status);
        });

        function onSuccess(data)
        {
            //$("#resultLog").html("Result: " + data);
            console.log(data[0].Name);
        }
```

Here , after calling web service, it has to return JSON data, but it didn't return anything. In firebug, inside the function onSucess, it shows 'null' for data. 
Do i miss anything here? Y does it show '403' forbidden error? Since i'm calling the scripts from the server  where the web service located, i think its not cross domain issue. I'm using this in Jquery mobile. Help needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using firebug to see the error 403?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what reason an unspecified service has for saying you don't have permission to access it?

Comment: @Ives yes. I use firebug

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it.. There was problem with URL.

Comment: and why don't you explain what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your web service is probably not script enabled using the attribute:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Answer (score 0):

do you build the web-service through wizard? i think the web service url should be "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/Y_NAME/REST/xxx.asmx"

Comment: no. its .aspx only. Even i tried with .asmx, its not working.

Comment: do you use IIS? there may be some configures of the IIS cause this, please pay attention to the "file type" filed of IIS properties dialog, make sure the .aspx file type be in the configure.